# Problem with position of new view using presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I am trying to add a new view to my app using `presentModalViewController`.

```
ASpotImageViewController *aSpotImage = [[ASpotImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ASpotImageView" bundle:nil spotID:spotid];
aSpotImage.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
//NSLog(@"frame is %@", aSpotImage.view.frame);
//NSLog(@"origin is %@", aSpotImage.view.frame.origin);
NSLog(@"description is %@", aSpotImage.description);
[aSpotImage setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self presentModalViewController:aSpotImage animated:YES];
```

But when I use this, the new view appears about 40 pixels or so down the screen, and the bottom is cut off. What could be causing this? I don't have this problem in other cases where I use this code.

Answer (score 0):

Gurooj, are you implementing try this

```
UINavigationController *nextController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aSpotImage];
[self presentModalViewController: nextController animated: YES];
```

the white space is usually the height of navigation bar, I guess?

Comment: That only made a new blank navigation bar appear on the screen. It actually leaves a black space, which is the same color as the new view I am trying to push. But the parent view has a background of white. Which only confuses me more.

Answer (score 0):

Your current container is having frame of `(320,440,0,40)` hence when you present on it it appears to be offset'ed by that much amount, although in reality its just adding it to the location `(0,0)` with respect to the parent container. The fix would be to readjust the frame accordingly of your current view or the parent view.

Comment: How would I do that? I have tried adjusting the frame manually and it does not seem to change anything in the modal view controller.

Comment: I am facing the same problem on the iPad, even when in Landscape mode, if I check the frame it tells me {0,0},{768,1024}  which is the size for portrait mode.